# thread-safety of const reference value in range-based for loop in a multi-threading environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, thread-safety

Suppose I have following piece of c++ code:

```
    threadpool thread_pool;
    map<Key, Value> map;
    for (const std::pair<Key, Value> & element : map) {
       thread_pool.Add([](const Value& value) {
       } (element); 
    }
    thread_pool.Join();
```

Is it thread-safe to pass by 'const reference' when the function uses a temporary value 'element' from range-based loop?
In other words, will it be deterministic that, the first thread is assigned the first returned kv pair from map, the second thread is assigned the second kv pair from map, etc?

If it's not thread-safe, and value is very expensive to copy, what's a good practice to solve this type of problem? Thanks!

Comment: missing one closing parent

Comment: I would say this all depends on what exactly the mysterious `threadpool` thing does exactly. One could guess; but one could be wrong…

Comment: If `threadpool` uses `std::thread`, that's safe because `std::thread` internally performs decay copies onto the new thread's stack space. Thus the new thread has a copy of the value, which is then passed to the lambda by const reference.

Comment: @VTT If `Key` is non-const, then `element` really _is_ a temporary because a `map` stores its keys as const objects.. `typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;` It's safer to use `const auto & element`

Comment: @LWimsey Using a pointer is even safer, as pointers don't implicitly create temps